# Docker compose with .Net micro services project

Tags: c#, docker-compose, microservices

I have a microservice project written in C# using ASP.NET Web Api projects. Every service has its own database. And every service works fine and connects/migrates everything to database when I run docker compose, but only two services which are using SQL Server database work very unstable. Every time I need to restart the containers (it doesn't connect from the first time):

[error in container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtNdj.png)

Even though, I have written following things:

this is database in docker compose

```
  orderdb:
    container_name: orderdb
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: somePassword...132
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1402:1433"
    volumes:
      - orders_data:/var/opt/mssql/orders
```

Service itself:

```
  ordering.api:
    container_name: ordering.api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - "ConnectionStrings:OrderingConnectionString=Server=orderdb;Database=OrderDb;Integrated Security=false;TrustServerCertificate=True;User Id=sa;Password=<password>;"
      - "EventBusSettings:HostAddress=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672"
    depends_on:
      - orderdb
      - rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "8004:80"
```

And also, I specified this in Program.cs (EmableRetryOnFailure)

```
services.AddDbContext<OrderContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("OrderingConnectionString"),
                opt => opt.EnableRetryOnFailure()));
```

What can I do in order to avoid this error when starting containers?

I thought that "depends_on:" in docker compose will help, and `EnableRetryOnFailure` method as options in `DbContext` as well, but it didn't